# avoid error in ssis package using winscpcommand

Tags: ssis, winscp, ssis-2012

Hi I have doubt  in ssis using winscp commands on excuteprocess task

I need download/move .zip file from remote server to local server machine.
Here I follow few steps:

```
step1:I install   winscp software in local server .
step2: I configure winscp settings with hostnameand username and pwd it working fine.

step3: I tried to implement ssis package using executeprocess task
there I given like below seetings in execute process task
executable:
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe

Arguments:
WinSCP /command "open ""sftp://uesrname:pwdhostname""" "get ""remoterservrpath"" localpath" "exit"
```

after that I ran execute process task.then file is moved from remoteserver to localserver path location
then imedentaily package failed with below error message

```
[Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" "WinSCP /command "open ""
sftp://usernamepwdhostname""" "get ""test.zip""
 C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\test.zip" "exit"" at "", 
The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
```

here usernamepwdhostname I did not share orignal.I mention similay format.
zip file is moved from remote to local server location.its fine.but I am getting  package error after move the .zip file

please tell me how to avoid this error in ssis package level

Comment: You should run the WinSCP command directly in a command window and see if any useful error messages come up, and then resolve them

Comment: in the command window does not show any error.there working fine.in ssis package level aslo file is download after that package fail to given above error information.

Comment: I suggest you post the output of the command window in the question so anyone else can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the arguments field, remove the `WinSCP` part at the start

executable:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe`

Arguments:

`/command "open ""sftp://uesrname:pwdhostname""" "get ""remoterservrpath"" localpath" "exit"`

Comment: Hi when I ran  above arguments and executable commands on BIDS environment its working fine.same package I create job schedule using sql server agent job. there its failing  with same error [Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" "WinSCP /command "open ""
sftp://usernamepwdhostname""" "get ""test.zip""
 C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\test.zip" "exit"" at "", 
The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0". can you please tell how to avoid this situation in sql server agent envirnoment.

Comment: You command line is still incorrect. You still have the redundant _WinSCP_ in the arguments. Maybe you didn't deploy your package.

Comment: No as per given command syntax only I followed and its working fine in BIDS level then I deploy same package in server there I Scheduled package and run it but its given same error message in agent job.teps: in the steps table: i given step: test
steptype:sql server integration package
server:test
Package: testpackage
select 32 bit runtime please tell me how to avoid this error in sql server agent job

Comment: Sorry I can't help it really seems like it hasn't been deployed because it's showing an error identical to the one that you were getting in BIDS _before_ you fixed it. It's like it's running a package with the old error in it still. Perhaps double check your deployment. Can you use this link to confirm the package deployment date and version matches your BIDS version: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a897b98-5de1-4f62-af8b-6f56cf765d7d/in-ssisdb-catalog-is-it-possible-to-look-at-package-version-build-number?forum=sqlintegrationservices